# When to link the View to data?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

I have a XAML / WPF View that currently calls a function which pulls in data (EF / LINQ) just after InitializeComponent().  However, if I try to populate the data at a later time (via a button instead), it doesn't return any data.

Two things:

1) Is there a better event (such as ContetRendered) that I should call the function from
2) Why would it be that the button, which calls the same event as on loading doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't call for unnecessary functions in the constructor. If you'll get any exception during that function your final exception will be "Could not initialize" instead of the exception you need.
   You can use `Window.Loaded` instead

   ```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
   ```
2. Show us some code we can help you out

Comment: It's something at my end.  I just moved some of the code into my testbed - and it worked straight away......here we go.....Thanks for the help Tzah.